# Add ASCII comments to a C binary?

Tags: c, binary, comments

I have extrememly small amount of experience with C programming.

The operating system is Linux. When you do `less` on a program file it shows a bunch of random characters, but it also shows some of the readable ASCII characters in the original C source code.

Is there a way to force comments to show up in the binary, preferably near the beginning of the program file so that someone could get an idea of what this is used for? The formatting of the comments does not have to be pretty, a continuous line of text is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comments are only present in the source code and will not be present in the binary. In case you find any readable text in the binary, it is because you came across string literals used by the program.

Binaries should only be read by computers and not humans, so it doesn't make any sense to include comments in them anyhow.

If you would for reasons unknown need something like a binary with comments, then generate a *disassembly* from the C source. It will contain the machine code together with the C code and C code comments.

That being said, you *could* force the program to link a string to the binary even if that string isn't used by the program, by adding something like:

```
volatile const char foo [] = "STOP LOOKING AT MY BINARY!";
```

Comment: Thank you this was a good idea. However the placement appears sketchy. I can place it in different areas of the source code, but it ends up in a seemingly unrelated area of the binary.

Comment: @Westrock: string constants will be stored in the `.rodata` section of the binary, regardless of where they appear in the source code (at least for ELF).

Answer (score 0):

In some formats, you can add text strings to an object file (program files are also object files, the term "binary" is missleading as this includes all non-text files) in a special *section*. However, this requires a deeper knowledege about C and the format of object files and is implementation/OS specific.

You can - OTOH - print some explanatory text from your program. Just try `less -h` for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Binaries should not be streamed with the `less` utility, and in less enlightened days you could seriously jack up your terminal settings by doing so.  It's safer to use the `strings` or `objdump` utilities to search for strings in binaries.

There's no *good* way to add comments to a binary file as such; binary formats are not meant to be human-readable, and don't generally allow free-form text.  As Lundin suggests, you can add some string objects to your source code that can be extracted from the compiled binary. Here's an example using the `objdump` facility:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
  const char *str = "This is a test of the Emergency Broadcast System.";
  puts( str );
  return 0;
}
```

After compiling, we can extract the constant string data as follows:

```
[fbgo448@n9dvap997]~/prototypes/words: objdump -d -j.rodata -C foo

foo:     file format elf64-x86-64

Disassembly of section .rodata:

0000000000400610 <_IO_stdin_used>:
  400610:       01 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 54 68 69 73 20 69 73 20     ........This is
  400620:       61 20 74 65 73 74 20 6f 66 20 74 68 65 20 45 6d     a test of the Em
  400630:       65 72 67 65 6e 63 79 20 42 72 6f 61 64 63 61 73     ergency Broadcas
  400640:       74 20 53 79 73 74 65 6d 2e 00                       t System..
```

In the ELF format, string constants are stored in the `.rodata` section of the binary file.

This is about as pretty as it gets, though.